# Referring to common function in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have data coming to XSLT, when any of two conditions get satisfied in XSLT.

`when(first condition satisfies)` then some validations on incoming data and then "common logic"
`otherwise if(second condition satisfies)` then some validations on incoming data and then "common logic"

Here i am writing common logic two times for both the conditions. How can i write that logic only once and make my conditions refer to that when any one of them satisfied. in simple words, i wnat to make it a function and call it, but couldnt use xsl:function tag as its not supported my xsl version.

i can write `when(first or second satisfies)` but validations to be done differs before i go to common logic..provide me suggestions how can i write common logic only once here.

Thanks.

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: You could possibly used named templates here... `<xsl:template name='commonlogic'>` which you then call with `xsl:call-template`. If you could show some existing code samples, it would help us give a more precise answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't move forward to XSLT 2.0, then named templates (called using xsl:call-template) are the only thing available to you.

Comment: hi, i cant copy code, but it goes like this :::::::::any one of the methods will come. when first method, validate it, when validation fails,then exit program,else call a weblink. when second method, validate it, when validation fails,then exit program,else call a weblink.  so here i want to call that 'else call a web link' common to both methods. it should be called if validation get successful for any of the method.

Comment: I can't quite see how your comment relates to my answer to your original question.